# How can I join these tables and make it work

Tags: sql

I want to join the tables author, paper and interest, however, I cant join the interest table without screwing the results over.

Ive tried joining the interest table, but the results dont work.

The question is- There are some academics that have written more than 12 papers and there are some
academics are interested in fields that have the word “database” in the title. List the
academic number of each academic that meet either or both of these conditions.

Relations-

```
DEPARTMENT( deptnum , descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
ACADEMIC( acnum , deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
PAPER( panum , title)
AUTHOR( panum*, acnum* )
FIELD( fieldnum , id, title)
INTEREST( fieldnum*, acnum* , descrip)
```

```sql
SELECT AU.ACNUM, COUNT(*)
FROM AUTHOR AU JOIN PAPER PA ON AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM -- JOIN INTEREST INT ON AU.ACNUM = INT.ACNUM THIS SCREWS UP THE RESULTS
WHERE AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 12
GROUP BY AU.ACNUM;
```

This is what I have so far, however, if I try to join the interest table to AU, it just messes up the results, where the Count(*) will be in the thousands, which is obviously not right at all.

I expect a result of all authors who have published more than 12 books, furthermore, if they are interested in %database%, then also include them

Comment: The WHERE clause can be removed, since it repeats the ON clause's join condition.

Comment: GROUP BY comes before HAVING.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. (And change 12 to 3 to minimize.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to Union the Authors with more than 12 papers and the ones who are interested in %database%

```
SELECT AU.ACNUM, COUNT(*) from AUTHOR AU
JOIN PAPER PA ON AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM
HAVING COUNT(*)>12

UNION 

SELECT AU.ACNUM, COUNT(*) from AUTHOR AU
JOIN INTEREST INT ON AU.ACNUM = INT.ACNUM
WHERE INT.DESCRIP like '%database%'
```

This should do the trick :)
Union removes the duplicates by default and you should get every Author one time with his count of Papers

Comment: This is it chief, thank you so much! I wasn't acquainted to the Union before

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work

```
 SELECT AU.ACNUM, fieldnum, COUNT(AU.ACNUM)
 FROM AUTHOR AU JOIN PAPER PA ON AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM 
left join INTEREST INT ON AU.ACNUM = INT.ACNUM 
GROUP BY AU.ACNUM, fieldnum
HAVING COUNT(AU.ACNUM) > 12
```

Answer (score 0):

These are separate conditions on different dimensions.  I would put the filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select a.*
from academic a
where exists (select 1
              from interest i
              where i.acnum = a.acnum and
                    i.descrip like '%database%'
             ) or
      (select count(*)
       from author au
       where au.acnum = a.acnum
      ) > 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select acnum
from author
group by acnum
having count(panum) >12 

UNION

(SELECT author.ACNUM
from AUTHOR JOIN INTEREST ON author.ACNUM = interest.ACNUM
WHERE lower(interest.DESCRIP) like '%database%');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.